# text with unicode escape sequences to unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode

suppose I have the string

```
test
'\\u0259'
```

Note the escaped backslash.

How do I convert it to the respective unicode string?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
>>> print('test \\u0259'.decode('unicode-escape'))
test ə
```

Comment: +1. Note that if you run python 3.x, you'll need `print(bytes('test \\u0259', 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))` instead.

Comment: How to get symbol **ə** without `print`?

Comment: `bytes('test \\u0259', 'ascii')` == `b'test \\u0259'`

Comment: what if we need to store the text in a json file

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi your answer from 2010 saved my brain from melting down here in 2021.  Legend.  SO says avoid "+1" stuff, but this deserved a special mention.

Comment: Alternatively to using `bytes`, you can just chain encode and decode if you start out with a unicode-string (Python 3). `'test \\u0259'.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')`