# Python regex match OR operator

Tags: python, regex, string, time

I'm trying to match time formats in AM or PM.

```
i.e. 02:40PM
     12:29AM
```

I'm using the following regex

```
timePattern = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)')
```

but it keeps returning only `AM` `PM` string without the numbers. What's going wrong?

Comment: perhaps use a capturing group

Comment: @Tommy: He is using a capturing group; that's what's causing the problem.  When the regex has capturing groups, `findall()` returns only those, not the full match.

Comment: Mind you, you could also avoid the group entirely, changing `(AM|PM)` to `[AP]M`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use a non capturing group `(?:` and reference to the match group.

Use `re.I` for case insensitive matching.

```
import re

def find_t(text):
    return re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}(?:am|pm)', text, re.I).group()
```

You can also use `re.findall()` for recursive matching.

```
def find_t(text):
    return re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}(?:am|pm)', text, re.I)
```

See [`demo`](https://eval.in/61126)

Answer (score 7):

Use a non-delimited capture group `(?:...)`:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> mystr = """
... 02:40PM
... 12:29AM
... """
>>> findall("\d{2}:\d{2}(?:AM|PM)", mystr)
['02:40PM', '12:29AM']
>>>
```

Also, you can shorten your Regex to `\d\d:\d\d(?:A|P)M`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're accessing group 1, when you need to be accessing group 0.

The groups in your regex are as follows:

```
\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)
           |-----|  - group 1
|----------------|  - group 0 (always the match of the entire pattern)
```

You can access the entire match via:

```
timePattern.match('02:40PM').group(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not capturing the Hour, minute fields:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile('(\d{2}:\d{2}(?:AM|PM))')
>>> r.search('02:40PM').group()
'02:40PM'
>>> r.search('Time is 12:29AM').group()
'12:29AM'
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you accidentally grabbing the 1st cluster (the stuff in that matches the portion of the pattern in the parentheses) instead of the "0st" cluster (which is the whole match)?