# How to avoid grouping in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Hello I am trying to parse a string like '2.2.2.2-22'
while using python re.findall function I am getting two groups:
I don't understand what is wrong with the RE:

```
re.findall(r"([\d.]+(-\d+)?)",  "2.2.2.2-22")
```

This gives me result as: [('2.2.2.2-22', '-22')]
I do not want the second group. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821487/python-regex-match-or-operator/19821774#19821774

Comment: A good place to look for Python regex questions is https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the grouping you can use `?:`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"([\d.]+(?:-\d+)?)",  "2.2.2.2-22")
['2.2.2.2-22']
```

It will force that group to exists, but it will not catch and return the value.

Comment: @hwnd that won't capture the string OP is after