# Scraping Google Images using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, urllib2

Now, I have been trying to scrape google images using the following code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import os
import time
import requests
import re
import urllib2
import re
from threading import Thread
import json
#Assuming I have a folder named Pictures1, the images are downloaded there. 
def threaded_func(url,i):
     raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
     cntr = len([i for i in os.listdir("Pictures1") if image_type in i]) + 1
     f = open("Pictures1/" + image_type + "_"+ str(total), 'wb')
     f.write(raw_img)
     f.close()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://images.google.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/input[1]')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("parrot")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
image_type = "parrot_defG"
images=[]
total=0
time.sleep(10)
for a in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rg_meta'):
     link =json.loads(a.text)["ou"]
     thread = Thread(target = threaded_func, args = (link,total))
     thread.start()
     thread.join()
     total+=1
```

I tried to open the image results page of google using Selenium and then notice that every div has class 'rg-meta' and it is followed by JSON code .

I tried to access it using .text . The 'ou' index of JSON has the source of the image I am trying to download. I am trying to get all such divs with class 'rg-meta' and downloading the images. But it shows the error **" NO JSON OBJECT CAN BE DECODED"** and I have no idea what to do.

EDIT:
This is what I am talking about :

```
    <div class="rg_meta">{"cl":3,"id":"FqCGaup9noXlMM:","isu":"kids.britannica.com","itg":false,"ity":"jpg","oh":600,"ou":"http://media.web.britannica.com/eb-media/89/89689-004-4C85E0F0.jpg","ow":380,"pt":"grain weevil -- Kids Encyclopedia | Children\u0026#39;s Homework Help ...","rid":"EusB0pk_sLg7vM","ru":"http://kids.britannica.com/comptons/art-143712/grain-or-granary-weevil","s":"grain weevil","sc":1,"st":"Kids Britannica","th":282,"tu":"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcQPbgXbRVzOicvPfBRtAkLOpJwy_wDQEC6a2q0BuTsUx-s0-h4b","tw":179}</div>
```

Check the "ou" index of the JSON. Please help me extract it.

Forgive me for my ignorance.

This is how I have solved it by making the following update :

```
    for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="rg_meta"]'):
        atext = a.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        link =json.loads(atext)["ou"]
        print link
        thread = Thread(target = threaded_func, args = (link,total))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        total+=1
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the contexts of a.text. If yes provide that output. What else have you tried to debug the problem you are experiencing

Comment: Yes @GiannisSpiliopoulos , Tried to print contents of .text. Shows blank in my terminal. I assumed the text might be unicode so I tried  to convert it to JSON by using json.dumps(). It didnt work either.

Comment: what does `a` prints ?

Comment: I am unclear how converting a unicode string to json would help you with that...  In any case try  printing the source of the whole page (`print(driver.page_source)`) and check if your assumptions are correct.

Comment: @SatishGarg , The following : <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="f18279af-edef-4420-8aad-1c305db29fa5", element="ad644d31-fd22-412e-881e-7cf51035779a")>

Comment: @GiannisSpiliopoulos, Please see my edit to know what I am trying to talk about.

Comment: @Kartavya Try my answer as it is working for me.

Comment: Throws this error @SatishGarg : selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.

Comment: @SatishGarg : Can you please provide that particular snippet of code where you replaced the line.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing:

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rg_meta')` with `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="rg_meta"]/text()')`

and `a.text` with `a`

will resolve your issue.

The resultant code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import os
import time
import requests
import re
import urllib2
import re
from threading import Thread
import json
#Assuming I have a folder named Pictures1, the images are downloaded there. 
def threaded_func(url,i):
     raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
     cntr = len([i for i in os.listdir("Pictures1") if image_type in i]) + 1
     f = open("Pictures1/" + image_type + "_"+ str(total), 'wb')
     f.write(raw_img)
     f.close()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://images.google.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/input[1]')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("parrot")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
image_type = "parrot_defG"
images=[]
total=0
time.sleep(10)
for a in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="rg_meta"]/text()'):
     link =json.loads(a)["ou"]
     thread = Thread(target = threaded_func, args = (link,total))
     thread.start()
     thread.join()
     total+=1
```

Printing **link** results in :

```
http://media.web.britannica.com/eb-media/89/89689-004-4C85E0F0.jpg
```

Comment: Not working for me, Please provide the snippet where u made the change. That will be extremely helpful. Thank You.

Comment: even after correcting it to, for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(...), there is an error : TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: Sorry, your code is not working :( :(
The line is :  link =json.loads(a)["ou"] 
and the error is : TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Can you add a traceback to the error you are receiving?

Comment: See, the line is , link =json.loads(a)["ou"]  and the error is : TypeError: expected string or buffer , this is probably because 'a' is a selenium element and not a string.

Comment: I solved it using .get_attribute("innerHtml"), The snippet is in the update of my question. Thank You so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since parsing with `selenium` is quite time-consuming, you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library to achieve the same results.

I'll show you how to parse images (including images with full resolution) from the [inline JSON](https://dev.to/serpapi/13-ways-to-scrape-any-public-data-from-any-website-1bn9#inline-json) which would be a lot faster.

Since the page is rendered dynamically we will also need to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract data from the inline JSON.

First, we can look for the title of the first image in the page source (`Ctrl+U`) to find the matches we need, and if they are in the `<script>` elements, then most likely this is inline JSON. From there we can extract the data.

Next, we narrow the search by selecting the part of the code that contains the data we need:

```py
# https://regex101.com/r/RPIbXK/1
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
      
# https://regex101.com/r/NRKEmV/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\"b-GRID_STATE0\"(.*)sideChannel:\s?{}}', matched_images_data_json)
```

And after that we already find thumbnails and directly original images:

```py
# https://regex101.com/r/SxwJsW/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                       str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")
    
thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]
    
# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))
    
# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)
```

Check full code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-images-bs4#main.py).

```py
import requests, re, json, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

google_images = []

params = {    
    "q": "cat",                # search query
    "tbm": "isch",             # image results
    "hl": "en",                # language of the search
    "gl": "us"                 # country where search comes from
}
    
html = requests.get("https://www.google.co.in/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    
all_script_tags = soup.select("script")
    
# https://regex101.com/r/RPIbXK/1
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
      
# https://regex101.com/r/NRKEmV/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\"b-GRID_STATE0\"(.*)sideChannel:\s?{}}', matched_images_data_json)
    
# https://regex101.com/r/SxwJsW/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                       str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")
    
thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]
    
# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))
    
# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)
    
full_res_images = [
        bytes(bytes(img, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for img in matched_google_full_resolution_images
]
        
for index, (metadata, thumbnail, original) in enumerate(zip(soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'), thumbnails, full_res_images), start=1):
    google_images.append({
        "title": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["title"],
        "link": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["href"],
        "source": metadata.select_one(".fxgdke").text,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "original": original
    })

print(json.dumps(google_images, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output

```json
[
  
  {
    "title": "Domestic cat",
    "link": "https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/mammals/facts/domestic-cat",
    "source": "National Geographic",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRM50JpAefCcT9Alyo8H_v5iqsBbNB6A5CXD8Jgggs3UePzvzA9onL7ULKxBJ4JZxeWsSc&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://i.natgeofe.com/n/548467d8-c5f1-4551-9f58-6817a8d2c45e/NationalGeographic_2572187_square.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "cat - Wiktionary",
    "link": "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cat",
    "source": "Wiktionary",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKr5wT7rfkjkGvNeqgXjBmarC5ZNoZs-H2uMpML8O7Q4F9W-IlUQibBT6IPqyvX45NOgw&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg"
  },
  other results ...
]
```

---

Also you can use [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Example to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json

image_results = []
   
# search query parameters
params = {
    "engine": "google",               # search engine. Google, Bing, Yahoo, Naver, Baidu...
    "q": "cat",                       # search query
    "tbm": "isch",                    # image results
    "num": "100",                     # number of images per page
    "ijn": 0,                         # page number: 0 -> first page, 1 -> second...
    "api_key": "..."                  # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
                                      # other query parameters: hl (lang), gl (country), etc  
}
    
search = GoogleSearch(params)         # where data extraction happens
    
images_is_present = True
while images_is_present:
    results = search.get_dict()       # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
# checks for "Google hasn't returned any results for this query."
    if "error" not in results:
        for image in results["images_results"]:
            if image["original"] not in image_results:
                    image_results.append(image["original"])
                
# update to the next page
        params["ijn"] += 1
    else:
        images_is_present = False
        print(results["error"])

print(json.dumps(image_results, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
  "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eX2qFMC8cFo/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/QMJh_AV-7ThLXG3QFYkn7KXe8dQ=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/facts-about-tuxedo-cats-554704-hero-6fcf332fd5ee4d93aecc4bcd3657396c.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/82/Sylvester_the_Cat.svg/800px-Sylvester_the_Cat.svg.png",
  "https://www.purina.co.uk/sites/default/files/styles/square_medium_440x440/public/2022-06/Bengal.02.jpg?h=16d99826&itok=-mU4KnIM",
  "https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/5mrNYjDpNn0GnXD_crwBDGIijcs=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/persian-cats-gallery-4121944-hero-f5c237b8c6404655afb1e1bbae219ba5.jpg",
  "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CPISexQPvQw/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "https://www.purina.co.uk/sites/default/files/2020-12/Cat%20Pregnancy%20Information%20%26%20AdviceTEASER.jpg",
  "https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/Re5vfPPvJhcRfTP22om9ivmFhJM=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/cat-meowing-57b738885f9b58cdfda9a497.jpg",
  other results ...
]
```

There's a [Scrape and download Google Images with Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-images-with-python/) blog post if you need a little bit more code explanation.