# (selenium) Can't find image element in Google image more than 20

Tags: python, selenium, google-image-search

I'm trying to scrape google image using selenium, chrome-driver.

I copied the Xpath of image elements and used find_element_by_xpath.
But selenium finds no more than the first 20 image elements of the page.

Is there any way to find more?

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_window_size(800, 600)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=a+dog&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi-59_iiZ_oAhWCIZQKHTaWB5MQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=a+dog&gs_l=img.3..0l5j0i7i30l5.29034.29325..29590...0.0..0.130.258.0j2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.10szHAao5lM&ei=5ntvXr7cNoLD0AS2rJ6YCQ')

for i in range(1, 10):
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
     time.sleep(1)

for i in range(1,100):
    img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[' +str(i) +']/a[1]/div[1]/img')
    print(img)
    src = img.get_attribute('src')
    print(src)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "./dog/" + str(i) +".png")



driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have this kind of code in your script "options.add_argument("--headless")", comment it, and run again, a chrome browser will pop-up and you will see that the images is grouped only by pages.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use `selenium` for scraping Google Images, as it may take a lot of system resources (RAM, CPU) and takes a lot of time in the process.

Since the data you need is rendered dynamically, you can do this with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) extracting data from inline JSON.

To do that, we can search for the first image title in the page source (`Ctrl+U`) to find the matches we need and if there are any in the `<script>` elements, then it is most likely an inline JSON. From there we can extract data.

Sequentially using regular expressions we find the data we need:

```py
# https://regex101.com/r/eteSIT/1
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))

matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
  
# https://regex101.com/r/BK0ePR/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

# https://regex101.com/r/Jt5BJW/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")

thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]

# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))

# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)

full_res_images = [
        bytes(bytes(img, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for img in matched_google_full_resolution_images
]
```

Full code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-images-using-bs4#main.py).

```py
import requests, re, json, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
  }

params = {
    "q": "auto",                  # search query
    "tbm": "isch",                # image results
    "hl": "en",                   # language of the search
    "gl": "us",                   # country where search comes fro
  }

html = requests.get("https://google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

google_images = []
all_script_tags = soup.select("script")

# https://regex101.com/r/eteSIT/1
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))

matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
  
# https://regex101.com/r/BK0ePR/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

# https://regex101.com/r/Jt5BJW/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")

thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]

# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))

# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)

full_res_images = [
        bytes(bytes(img, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for img in matched_google_full_resolution_images
]
    
for index, (metadata, thumbnail, original) in enumerate(zip(soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'), thumbnails, full_res_images), start=1):
    google_images.append({
        "title": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["title"],
        "link": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["href"],
        "source": metadata.select_one(".fxgdke").text,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "original": original
    })

print(json.dumps(google_images, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output

```py
[
  {
    "title": "Auto rickshaw - Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_rickshaw",
    "source": "en.wikipedia.org",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTb6dAnJXx_S5XG9cNAoXT9yFaEkFa8vgxc8Av87_zrWAjRcblL9BvkXpGf4WMNCJdQi7M&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Bajaj_auto-rickshaw_in_Sri_Lanka.jpg"
  },
  other results ...
]
```

---

Or you can use [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Simple code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json

image_results = []
   
# search query parameters
params = {
    "engine": "google",               # search engine. Google, Bing, Yahoo, Naver, Baidu...
    "q": "auto",                      # search query
    "tbm": "isch",                    # image results
    "num": "100",                     # number of images per page
    "ijn": 0,                         # page number: 0 -> first page, 1 -> second...
    "api_key": "..."                  # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
                                      # other query parameters: hl (lang), gl (country), etc  
}
    
search = GoogleSearch(params)         # where data extraction happens
    
images_is_present = True
while images_is_present:
    results = search.get_dict()       # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
# checks for "Google hasn't returned any results for this query."
    if "error" not in results:
        for image in results["images_results"]:
            if image["original"] not in image_results:
                    image_results.append(image["original"])
                
# update to the next page
        params["ijn"] += 1
    else:
        images_is_present = False
        print(results["error"])

print(json.dumps(image_results, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  "https://www.maersk.com/~/media_sc9/maersk/news/expert-opinion/images/2022/08/global-auto-industry-raring-to-go-banner_1024x576.jpg?h=576&w=1024&hash=B754547ED408383F077B871A06A8C8A2",
  "https://cdn05.carsforsale.com/4570107f9152815bf7ab06037a21cc7d/800x600/2012-lexus-es-350-base-4dr-sedan.jpg",
  "https://cdn05.carsforsale.com/00d6bfedaa178471ae397a6b1103f8486e/800x600/2013-chevrolet-sonic-lt-auto-4dr-sedan.jpg",
  "https://www.thenewsminute.com/sites/default/files/Autos-in-Bangalore_1200-Picxy.jpg",
  "https://cdn.bajajauto.com/-/media/Assets/bajajauto/three-wheelers/re/Calculator_image/savings_calculator_image_re_new.ashx",
  "https://etimg.etb2bimg.com/thumb/msid-87103472,imgsize-34400,width-1200,height-900,overlay-etauto/delhi-to-soon-have-over-4k-e-autos-on-roads-registration-opens.jpg",
  other results ...
]
```

There's a [Scrape and download Google Images with Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-images-with-python/) blog post if you need more explanation.