# Unable to scrape google images selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following script which i want it to scrapes google images. It clicks on the image first and then clicks on next `(>)` button to switch to the next image.

It downloads the first image, but when it's turn of the second image then it throws me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/intel/Desktop/Scrappr/image_scrape.pyw", line 40, in <module>
    attribute_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'n3VNCb'))).get_attribute("src")
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

**My code :**

```
import requests
import shutil
import time
import urllib
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
             'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'

options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\setups\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=mac+beautiful+ui&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiL3ILMveToAhWGCHIKHVPNAScQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=mac+beautiful+ui&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECAAQQzoCCAA6BQgAEIMBOgYIABAFEB46BggAEAgQHlDPI1iEUWCgU2gAcAB4AIAByAKIAd8dkgEHMC40LjkuM5gBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=Q9-TXsuuMoaRyAPTmoe4Ag&bih=657&biw=1360")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("rg_i").click()

i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    time.sleep(5)
    attribute_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.n3VNCb'))).get_attribute("src")
    print(attribute_value)
    resp = requests.get(attribute_value, stream=True)
    local_file = open(r'C:/users/intel/desktop/local_image'+ str(i) + '.jpg', 'wb')
    resp.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, local_file)
    del resp
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[2]/div""").click()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've tidied up and refactored a bit your code. The final result is capable of grabbing n amount of images for keywords of your choice (see `SEARCH_TERMS`):

```py
import base64
import os
import requests
import time

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION = r'C:\Users\intel\Downloads\setups\chromedriver.exe'
SEARCH_TERMS = ['very', 'hot', 'chicks']
TARGET_SAVE_LOCATION = os.path.join(r'c:\test', '_'.join([x.capitalize() for x in SEARCH_TERMS]),  r'{}.{}')
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(TARGET_SAVE_LOCATION)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(TARGET_SAVE_LOCATION))

def check_if_result_b64(source):
    possible_header = source.split(',')[0]
    if possible_header.startswith('data') and ';base64' in possible_header:
        image_type = possible_header.replace('data:image/', '').replace(';base64', '')
        return image_type
    return False

def get_driver():

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                 'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'
    options = Options()
    #options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    options.add_argument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt")

    new_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION, options=options)
    new_driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={'+'.join(SEARCH_TERMS)}&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X")
    return new_driver



driver = get_driver()

first_search_result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a/div/img')[0]
first_search_result.click()

right_panel_base = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'''//*[@data-query="{' '.join(SEARCH_TERMS)}"]''')))
first_image = right_panel_base.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-noaft="1"]')[0]
magic_class = first_image.get_attribute('class')
image_finder_xp = f'//*[@class="{magic_class}"]'


# initial wait for the first image to be loaded
# this part could be improved but I couldn't find a proper way of doing it
time.sleep(3)

# initial thumbnail for "to_be_loaded image"
thumbnail_src = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(image_finder_xp)[-1].get_attribute("src")

for i in range(10):

    # issue 4: All image elements share the same class. Assuming that you always click "next":
    # The last element is the base64 encoded thumbnail version is of the "next image"
    # [-2] element is the element currently displayed
    target = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(image_finder_xp)[-2]

    # you need to wait until image is completely loaded:
    # first the base64 encoded thumbnail will be displayed
    # so we check if the displayed element src match the cached thumbnail src.
    # However sometimes the final result is the base64 content, so wait is capped
    # at 5 seconds.
    wait_time_start = time.time()
    while (target.get_attribute("src") == thumbnail_src) and time.time() < wait_time_start + 5:
        time.sleep(0.2)
    thumbnail_src = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(image_finder_xp)[-1].get_attribute("src")
    attribute_value = target.get_attribute("src")
    print(attribute_value)

    # issue 1: if the image is base64, requests get won't work because the src is not an url
    is_b64 = check_if_result_b64(attribute_value)
    if is_b64:
        image_format = is_b64
        content = base64.b64decode(attribute_value.split(';base64')[1])
    else:
        resp = requests.get(attribute_value, stream=True)
        temp_for_image_extension = BytesIO(resp.content)
        image = Image.open(temp_for_image_extension)
        image_format = image.format
        content = resp.content
    # issue 2: if you 'open' a file, later you have to close it. Use a "with" pattern instead
    with open(TARGET_SAVE_LOCATION.format(i, image_format), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)
    # issue 3: this Xpath is bad """//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[2]/div""" if page layout changes, this path breaks instantly
    svg_arrows_xpath = '//div[@jscontroller]//a[contains(@jsaction, "click:trigger")]//*[@viewBox="0 0 24 24"]'
    next_arrow = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(svg_arrows_xpath)[-3]
    next_arrow.click()
```

Comment: Search term : very, hot, chicks . Great! Well thanks a lot for your help. I will check that out in my PC, ASAP and then get back to you whether it worked or how it worked 

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I doubt that Google allows scraping on Search. You should check out https://www.google.com/robots.txt to find out.

That being said, I think there is a problem in your `WebDriverWait` method, though I am not sure what exactly it is. Since you already have your driver wait before that with `time.sleep`, I just tried to find the element directly, and it worked:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    time.sleep(5)
    attribute_value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img.n3VNCb").get_attribute("src") # NEW LINE
    print(attribute_value)
    resp = requests.get(attribute_value, stream=True)
    local_file = open(r'C:/users/intel/desktop/local_image'+ str(i) + '.jpg', 'wb')
    resp.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, local_file)
    del resp
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[2]/div""").click()
```

Comment: Selenium is just a library to manipulate a browser using a webdriver. It uses an actual browser (*in this case Chrome*) to do the scrapping. `robots.txt` has nothing to do with browsers access; it's mainly there for spider bots directions. You can use Selenium to scrape Google Search results.

Comment: Yeah you are right @ChristosLytras Well i have tried many image scraping API's but none of them worked. Did you have any working library or API suggestion which is working?

Comment: @Minipekka my comment is for **broti's** answer. Your approach of using *Selenium Webdriver* with *Chrome* to scrape *Google Search* results is totally fine and **Trapli's** answer is sufficient enough for what you want.

Comment: Regardless of `robots.txt`, just because you're using a browser doesn't mean that you're allowed to scrape google in an automated way. You violate the terms of use by doing this and Google will still try to thwart these scraping behaviors. It's really only a matter of time/volume until you hit something like a reCAPTCHA request. Depending what country you are in, it could also be illegal. Anyhow, what you _should_ do is have an API key and use the search APIs; circumventing the official API and its rate limits is committing fraud/abuse against Google.

Answer (score 0):

`selenium`  could take a lot of time and resources (CPU, RAM), so you can scrape Google Images data from inline JSON with using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library and [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

The data you need is located in [page source](https://serpapi.com/blog/13-ways-to-scrape-any-data-from-any-website/#page-source) in the inline JSON.

In order to locate and extract data from [inline JSON](https://serpapi.com/blog/13-ways-to-scrape-any-data-from-any-website/#inline-json) you need:

1. open page source `CTRL + U`;
2. find the data you need  with `CTRL + F` search option;
3. use regular expressions to extract parts of inline Json:

```py
# https://regex101.com/r/4OVJHX/1
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
      
# https://regex101.com/r/WELgPS/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\"b-GRID_STATE0\"(.*)sideChannel:\s?{}}', matched_images_data_json)
    
# https://regex101.com/r/gfpJGH/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                       str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")
    
thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]
    
# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))
    
# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)
```

Check full code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-google-images-bs4#main.py).

```py
import requests, re, json, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

google_images = []

params = {    
    "q": "mac beautiful ui",   # search query
    "tbm": "isch",             # image results
    "hl": "en",                # language of the search
    "gl": "us"                 # country where search comes fro
}
    
html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    
all_script_tags = soup.select("script")
    
# https://regex101.com/r/4OVJHX/1
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
      
# https://regex101.com/r/WELgPS/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\"b-GRID_STATE0\"(.*)sideChannel:\s?{}}', matched_images_data_json)
    
# https://regex101.com/r/gfpJGH/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                       str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")
    
thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]
    
# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))
    
# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)
    
full_res_images = [
        bytes(bytes(img, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for img in matched_google_full_resolution_images
]
        
for index, (metadata, thumbnail, original) in enumerate(zip(soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'), thumbnails, full_res_images), start=1):
    google_images.append({
        "title": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["title"],
        "link": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["href"],
        "source": metadata.select_one(".fxgdke").text,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "original": original
    })

print(json.dumps(google_images, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "macOS UI Design – The Best Free Resources & Inspiration | UXMISFIT.COM",
    "link": "https://uxmisfit.com/2017/01/16/macos-ui-design-the-best-free-resources-inspiration/",
    "source": "UXMISFIT.COM",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8H9dXnxZVu_g0GVPY9np8a3ZkwsIFOBrO5No9EZic-X1ykSvWVVWrsGlXxL4sOr5j9lo&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://uxmisfit.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/alexander_2uikit-1024x576.png"
  },
  {
    "title": "Design a beautiful \"dark-mode\" ui for simple mac app | App design contest |  99designs",
    "link": "https://99designs.com/mobile-app-design/contests/design-beautiful-dark-mode-ui-simple-mac-app-847502",
    "source": "99Designs",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfOgfPHVtNLSGIUrfE7p0sNCVvFV-CZhxxfZ6wAIU2C037IjkZkInnB0nlKvCxwjOqGNc&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://images-platform.99static.com/mvyP91zYUsrpXUvhqBjNzDy4DqY=/3x0:1618x1615/500x500/top/smart/99designs-contests-attachments/99/99210/attachment_99210540"
  },
  other results ...
]
```

---

Also you can use [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Simple code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import json

image_results = []
   
# search query parameters
params = {
    "engine": "google",               # search engine. Google, Bing, Yahoo, Naver, Baidu...
    "q": "mac beautiful ui",          # search query
    "tbm": "isch",                    # image results
    "num": "100",                     # number of images per page
    "ijn": 0,                         # page number: 0 -> first page, 1 -> second...
    "api_key": "..."                  # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
                                      # other query parameters: hl (lang), gl (country), etc  
}
    
search = GoogleSearch(params)         # where data extraction happens
    
images_is_present = True
while images_is_present:
    results = search.get_dict()       # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
# checks for "Google hasn't returned any results for this query."
    if "error" not in results:
        for image in results["images_results"]:
            if image["original"] not in image_results:
                    image_results.append(image["original"])
                
# update to the next page
        params["ijn"] += 1
    else:
        images_is_present = False
        print(results["error"])

print(json.dumps(image_results, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/422170/screenshots/11461839/powered-kiss-principle_def.png?compress=1&resize=400x300",
  "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/226242/screenshots/18225016/media/3ab1bf230107da033342633cf7b09733.png?compress=1&resize=400x300",
  "https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/4045436/file/original-43340f87ef951b4da0343d93dba54373.png?resize=400x0",
  "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/2404/screenshots/15447041/media/d7861d9863e2305a0ad8adb415a662dd.png?compress=1&resize=400x300",
  "https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/4089487/file/original-6182d105d299d35d88d92043bf75c100.png?resize=400x0",
  "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/606683/screenshots/17054778/media/3d93194d1946de60585cefa299d9acd7.png?compress=1&resize=400x300",
  other results ...
]
```

There's a [Scrape and download Google Images with Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-images-with-python/) blog post if you need a little bit more code explanation.

Answer (score 0):

All The Answers Above are Way too Complicated and Some converting the base 64 image Code to actual Image.

**My Approach:**
If you Google for Image and Click on an Image, then you must remember that after clicking the image, a Image Dialog Appears on the right side of the Web Page (*Example Image Shown Below*) that contain the same image BUT in Bigger and Better Quality, that's because the side dialog image is directly loaded from the actual URL.

[image]

So My Approach is to Open Selenium by Giving Search Query in URL and Click on image with class *rg_i* and then that big dialog image also have a fixed class name that never changes, So find the *img* tag with that class name and get *src* attribute.

**Here's my Python Selenium Code to Download the Very First Image** (You can apply loop to download First n number of images):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
import time
import os


options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    driver.get(f"https://images.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=isch")

    # Wait for the page to load and render images (adjust the sleep time if needed)
    time.sleep(3)

    # Locate the image element using a CSS selector
    image = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'rg_i')
    image.click()
    time.sleep(3)                 

    # Find the img tag with class name "r48jcc" (or any one of the class names)
    img_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "r48jcc")

    img_src = img_element.get_attribute('src')

    #Displaying theImage URL on Console
    print(img_src)
        
    # Download the image
    response = requests.get(img_src)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open("downloaded_image.png", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print("Image downloaded successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download image with status code {response.status_code}.")

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred while using Selenium: {e}")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```