# Webscraping Google Images with Python and Selenium:code breaks when trying to download multiple images

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, xpath

I need to download a lot of images for a personal project and I wanted to use a script to download them automatically from Google.
I have found a script on Stackoverflow which works perfectly: I am able to open Chrome, download the first image but then the script breaks when trying to move to the second image.

Here is the code I have found:

```
import base64
import os
import requests
import time

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION = r'C:/pathtochromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
SEARCH_TERMS = ['cats', 'dogs']
TARGET_SAVE_LOCATION = os.path.join(r'D:\\Pictures\\test', '_'.join([x.capitalize() for x in SEARCH_TERMS]),  r'{}.{}')
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(TARGET_SAVE_LOCATION)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(TARGET_SAVE_LOCATION))

def check_if_result_b64(source):
    possible_header = source.split(',')[0]
    if possible_header.startswith('data') and ';base64' in possible_header:
        image_type = possible_header.replace('data:image/', '').replace(';base64', '')
        return image_type
    return False

def get_driver():

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \\
                 'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'
    options = Options()
    #options.add_argument(\"--headless\")
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument(\"--disable-web-security\")
    options.add_argument(\"--allow-running-insecure-content\")
    options.add_argument(\"--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt\")

    new_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION, options=options)
    new_driver.get(f\"https://www.google.com/search?q={'+'.join(SEARCH_TERMS)}&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X\")
    return new_driver


driver = get_driver()

first_search_result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a/div/img')[0]
first_search_result.click()

right_panel_base = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'''//*[@data-query=\"{' '.join(SEARCH_TERMS)}\"]''')))
first_image = right_panel_base.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-noaft=\"1\"]')[0]
magic_class = first_image.get_attribute('class')
image_finder_xp = f'//*[@class=\"{magic_class}\"]'


# initial wait for the first image to be loaded
# this part could be improved but I couldn't find a proper way of doing it
time.sleep(3)

# initial thumbnail for \"to_be_loaded image\"
thumbnail_src = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(image_finder_xp)[-1].get_attribute(\"src\")

for i in range(10):

    # issue 4: All image elements share the same class. Assuming that you always click \"next\":
    # The last element is the base64 encoded thumbnail version is of the \"next image\"
    # [-2] element is the element currently displayed
    target = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(image_finder_xp)[-2]

    # you need to wait until image is completely loaded:
    # first the base64 encoded thumbnail will be displayed
    # so we check if the displayed element src match the cached thumbnail src.
    # However sometimes the final result is the base64 content, so wait is capped
    # at 5 seconds.
    wait_time_start = time.time()
    while (target.get_attribute(\"src\") == thumbnail_src) and time.time() < wait_time_start + 5:
        time.sleep(0.2)
    thumbnail_src = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(image_finder_xp)[-1].get_attribute(\"src\")
    attribute_value = target.get_attribute(\"src\")
    print(attribute_value)

    # issue 1: if the image is base64, requests get won't work because the src is not an url
    is_b64 = check_if_result_b64(attribute_value)
    if is_b64:
        image_format = is_b64
        content = base64.b64decode(attribute_value.split(';base64')[1])
    else:
        resp = requests.get(attribute_value, stream=True)
        temp_for_image_extension = BytesIO(resp.content)
        image = Image.open(temp_for_image_extension)
        image_format = image.format
        content = resp.content
    # issue 2: if you 'open' a file, later you have to close it. Use a \"with\" pattern instead
    with open(TARGET_SAVE_LOCATION.format(i, image_format), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)
    # issue 3: this Xpath is bad \"\"\"//*[@id=\"Sva75c\"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[2]/div\"\"\" if page layout changes, this path breaks instantly
    svg_arrows_xpath = '//div[@jscontroller]//a[contains(@jsaction, \"click:trigger\")]//*[@viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\"]'
    print(svg_arrows_xpath)
    print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(str(svg_arrows_xpath)))
    next_arrow = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(svg_arrows_xpath)[-3]
    next_arrow.click()
```

I think that the problem is caused by the last line  "driver.find_elements_by_xpath(svg_arrows_xpath)[-3]".

I think that the the code has changed and it is not pointing to the right element anymore.
Unfortunately, I have 0 knowledge of Selenium.

Could you please tell me  how to modify it to point to the right element?
Could you guys tell me how this works and how I could have solved it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see where is problem.

Comment: how did you copy this code to question? it has `\"` instead of `"` in many places but it is wrong and we can't copy and run it.

Comment: could you add link to question with this code? Maybe it is old question and it works some older Google. Pages may change design.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thank you very much you solved this problem :) To help other people I will leave the info you asked me:

Error: I was getting the same error which you got: "Exception: Element not interactable".
My Code: I copy-pasted it from a jupyter notebook, I thought I had it cleaned but I evidently thought wrong. Next time I will be more careful.
Link to the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190450/unable-to-scrape-google-images-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages can be redesigned and maybe this script was created for older Google.

But also Selenium is changing and older methods may not work in new versions.

I can find elements if I skip last part

```
    svg_arrows_xpath = '//div[@jscontroller]//a[contains(@jsaction, "trigger")]'
```

Element has also problem with function `.click()`
because Selenium see this element as `not interactive` and it can't click it.
But it can be clicked using `JavaScript` code.

```
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', next_arrow)
```

---

```
    svg_arrows_xpath = '//div[@jscontroller]//a[contains(@jsaction, "trigger")]'   #//*[@viewBox="0 0 24 24"]'
    
    #print(svg_arrows_xpath)
    
    found = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(svg_arrows_xpath)
    print('len(found):', len(found))

    next_arrow = found[-3]

    #next_arrow.click()
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', next_arrow)
```

Comment: Thank you, with this fix now the code works perfectly :) I want to be able to work with selenium in the future, what should I study to get a better understanding of it?

Comment: first you can read all [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). There is also [newsletter](https://elementalselenium.com/) but probably you can see the same in [archive](https://elementalselenium.com/tips). Authors of module [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) made page [ToScrape](http://toscrape.com/) which you can use to learn scraping.