# How do I scrape all the images from a google image search?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn neural network for visualization and want to use chickens as my example. I figured I can scrape all the pictures of chickens off google images since when I search for images of chickens on google I get a bunch of results that keep scrolling down. However, after I scraped all the images the length of my images are only 20. I thought the problem was the pictures might be indexed by pages but as i said, in my browser, there are no pages, there is only a single page that keeps scrolling down so I don't know how to scrape the rest of the pictures after the first 20.

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
import os 

os.mkdir('chickens')

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=chickens&client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=AOaemvLwoKYN8RyvBYe-XTRPazSsDAiQuQ:1641698866084&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLp_bt3KP1AhWHdt8KHZR9C-UQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1536&bih=711&dpr=1.25')



soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.findAll('img')
images = images[1:]

print(len(images))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but I think it will work...

First, googles server has to recognize you as a mobile client so you have a next button at the end of the screen
use this link for your search [https://www.google.com/search?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=en&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=chickens&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYdo4U4mFc_xRYkggo_zUXeCf6jUYWUjl&gbv=2&oq=chickens&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0i512i433j0i512i433i457j0i402l2j0i512l6.4571.6193.0.6957.8.7.0.1.1.0.134.611.6j1.7.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..0.8.613.OJ31YrPZ-B0'](https://www.google.com/search?q=chickens&hl=en&gbv=2&biw=1376&bih=732&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&ei=fmjaYZ3eIZK5qtsP2f2e8AY&start=40&sa=N)

Then since you have a next button you can then scrape the href of the 'next' button
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOJCG.png

after you have the href you can then do another requests.get(new url)

and repeat

[To visualize what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvemu.jpg)

[The next page you would get if you were to request the next button href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzWbj.jpg)

Comment: I know if you click on the link you will still get a default view but it changes when you make a requests.get(url)

Comment: what would the syntax be for me to find the next button? so my r variable when i request the url only gives 20 pictures in the first place which is where im scraping from. how can i make my requests.get receive more pictures?

Comment: I don't know much about beautiful soup and I don't know how well versed you are in python but I don't think it will be that hard to write a function to go through the html and find the buttons href. Look at the links I put at the bottom of my answer; they might help you.

Comment: im pretty comfortable with python as for bs im completely inexperienced. ive mostly coded algos in python and never any web dev stuff

Comment: Did my answer help at all or are you still a little confused?

Comment: This might help you find the href soup.find_all('a', {'class':'frGj1b'})

Comment: i will give it a shot. i was actually answering an algo problem for someone my bad

Comment: did not work. got 0 items. but i did get 33 images instead of 20 using the find_all for img

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a half-automation scraping case, so you may manually scroll the page to the end, and then use python to scrape all the images.

There could be a "show more" button when scrolling down the page, you can click it and continue. There are total 764 images found in my search and can be easily scraped with python.

findAll('img') will get all images including non-result ones. You may try some other libraries to do the scraping.

Answer (score 0):

We can scrape Google Images data from inline JSON because the data you need renders dynamically.

It can be extracted via [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). To do that, we can search for the first image title in the page source (`Ctrl+U`) to find the matches we need and if there are any in the `<script>>` elements, then it is most likely an inline JSON. From there we can extract data.

First of all, we use a regular expression to find the part of the code that contains the information we need about the images:

```py
# https://regex101.com/r/48UZhY/4
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
```

In the next step, we bring the returned part of the data and selecting only part of the JSON where images are located (thumbnail, original ones):

```py
matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
  
# https://regex101.com/r/VPz7f2/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\"b-GRID_STATE0\"(.*)sideChannel:\s?{}}', matched_images_data_json)
```

Then find thumbnails:

```py
# https://regex101.com/r/Jt5BJW/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")

thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]
```

And finally find images in original resolution:

```py
# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))

# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)

full_res_images = [
        bytes(bytes(img, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for img in matched_google_full_resolution_images
]
```

To get absolutely all images, you must use browser automation, such as `selenium` or `playwright`. Also, you can use the [`"ijn" URL parameter`](https://serpapi.com/images-results#api-parameters-ijn) that defines the page number to get (greater than or equal to 0).

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-all-images-from-a-google-image-search-bs4#main.py).

```py
import requests, re, json, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
  }

params = {
    "q": "chickens",              # search query
    "tbm": "isch",                # image results
    "hl": "en",                   # language of the search
    "gl": "us",                   # country where search comes fro
  }

html = requests.get("https://google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

google_images = []
all_script_tags = soup.select("script")

# https://regex101.com/r/eteSIT/1
matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))

matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
  
# https://regex101.com/r/VPz7f2/1
matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\"b-GRID_STATE0\"(.*)sideChannel:\s?{}}', matched_images_data_json)

# https://regex101.com/r/Jt5BJW/1
matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
    re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")

thumbnails = [bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails]

# removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))

# https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)

full_res_images = [
        bytes(bytes(img, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for img in matched_google_full_resolution_images
]
    
for index, (metadata, thumbnail, original) in enumerate(zip(soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'), thumbnails, full_res_images), start=1):
    google_images.append({
        "title": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["title"],
        "link": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["href"],
        "source": metadata.select_one(".fxgdke").text,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "original": original
    })

print(json.dumps(google_images, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Chicken - Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken",
    "source": "en.wikipedia.org",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTM_XkDqM-gjEHUeniZF4HYdjmA4G_lKckEylFzHxxa_SiN0LV4-6M_QPuCVMleDm52doI&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Male_and_female_chicken_sitting_together.jpg/640px-Male_and_female_chicken_sitting_together.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "Chickens | The Humane Society of the United States",
    "link": "https://www.humanesociety.org/animals/chickens",
    "source": "humanesociety.org",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYa5_tlXtxNpxDQAU02DWkwK2hVlB3lkY_ljILmh9ReKoVK_pT9TS2PV0-RUuOY5Kkkzs&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://www.humanesociety.org/sites/default/files/styles/1240x698/public/2018/06/chickens-in-grass_0.jpg?h=56ab1ba7&itok=uou5W86U"
  },
  {
    "title": "chicken | bird | Britannica",
    "link": "https://www.britannica.com/animal/chicken",
    "source": "britannica.com",
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCl4LDGrSpsA6eFOY3M1ITTH7KlIIkvctOHuB_CbztbDRsdE4KKJNwArQJVJ7WvwCVr14&usqp=CAU",
    "original": "https://cdn.britannica.com/07/183407-050-C35648B5/Chicken.jpg"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

Or you can use [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It`s a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Simple code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json

image_results = []
   
# search query parameters
params = {
    "engine": "google",               # search engine. Google, Bing, Yahoo, Naver, Baidu...
    "q": "chicken",                   # search query
    "tbm": "isch",                    # image results
    "num": "100",                     # number of images per page
    "ijn": 0,                         # page number: 0 -> first page, 1 -> second...
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY")   # your serpapi api key
                                      # other query parameters: hl (lang), gl (country), etc  
}
    
search = GoogleSearch(params)         # where data extraction happens
    
images_is_present = True
while images_is_present:
    results = search.get_dict()       # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
# checks for "Google hasn't returned any results for this query."
    if "error" not in results:
        for image in results["images_results"]:
            if image["original"] not in image_results:
                    image_results.append(image["original"])
                
# update to the next page
        params["ijn"] += 1
    else:
        images_is_present = False
        print(results["error"])

print(json.dumps(image_results, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  "https://www.spendwithpennies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/1200-Grilled-Chicken-Breast-22.jpeg",
  "https://assets.bonappetit.com/photos/6282c9277e593c16bfea9c61/2:3/w_2430,h_3645,c_limit/0622-Sweet-and-Sticky-Grilled-Chicken.jpg",
  "https://kristineskitchenblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/grilled-chicken-1200-square-0400-2.jpg",
  "https://thecozycook.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Creamy-Garlic-Chicken-f.jpg",
  "https://www.jocooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/instant-pot-chicken-breasts-1-10.jpg",
  "https://www.healthbenefitstimes.com/9/uploads/2018/04/Know-about-Chicken-and-health-benefits-702x459.png",
  "https://www.tasteofhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Air-Fryer-Rotisserie-Chicken_EXPS_FT22_237368_F_0128_1.jpg?fit=700,1024",
  "https://www.militarytimes.com/resizer/-1j4zK-eaI1KPote1gyV1fw9XVg=/1024x0/filters:format(png):quality(70)/cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublishing.com/archetype/BFPDC4MPLVGONPK2D5XXN7QOXI.png",
  # ...
]
```

There's a [Scrape and download Google Images with Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-images-with-python/) blog post if you need a little bit more code explanation.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Comment: never use temporary classes like `.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb` this can never be a solution since the class is dynamic and ll change its name.

Comment: @SergeyK CSS selectors (on Google Images) rarely change so it is still a solution. More importantly, the point of this answer is to show how to extract original resolution images rather than answer "what type of selectors is the most reliable".

Comment: Before copying the code, did you check that it works? I agree that changing the selector is quite rare, and as a one-time solution this is normal.