# How to get images from Google's search results using Mechanize

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, mechanize-python

I was trying to parse the HTML of Google's image search result and get the original link of the images.

So far I was successful in writing a Python code to get the HTML of Google's search using Python's Mechanize and BeautifulSoup.

Looking at Google's search results HTML source I found that Google is storing double encode of original image's URL in a div with class `rg_meta`, but the HTML I am receiving from Mechanize does not contain any such class. In fact, the whole new webpage is being returned through Mechanize.

I am aware of Google's image search APIs but I need to parse HTML this way. What am I doing wrong? Can I mask Mechanize as Chrome or a different browser?

This is a snippet of what I was trying. It's returning nothing:

```
import urllib
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urlparse

search = "cars"
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_proxies({"https": "10.0.2.88:3128"})
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla')]

html = browser.open("https://www.google.co.in/search?&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&q="+search+"&oq="+search)
htmltext=html.read()
print htmltext    
img_urls = []
formatted_images = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
#results = soup.findAll("a")
results = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "rg_meta" })
print results
```

Comment: "You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)..."

Comment: Care to answer how? i am new to python.

Comment: Google terms of use does not allow to use scripts on the web search. Try something like `pattern.web` http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web#services

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying but i had to shift to urllib2 to solve this problem,
Following code is parsing the google search page for images link.

```
search = search.replace(" ","%20")
  site= "http://www.google.co.in/search?q="+search+"&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:l"
  hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
         'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
         'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
         'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
         'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
         'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
  QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
  req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)

  try:
      QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
      page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
      print e.fp.read()  
  QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
  content = page.read()
  #print content
  soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
  results = soup.findAll("a")
  linkarray = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "rg_meta"})
  #print linkarray
  refer_rl=[]
  total=len(linkarray)
  i=0
  for divs in linkarray:
    i=i+1
    stri=str(divs)
    refer_url=stri.split('%3B')
    try:
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
        url=urllib.unquote(refer_url[2]).decode('utf8') 
        url=urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8') 
        #os.system('wget '+url)
        #f = open('links.txt', 'a')
        #f.write(url+'\n')
        form.textBrowser.append(url)
        form.progressBar.setProperty("value", i*100/total)
        time.sleep(0.05)

    except:
        continue
  #os.system('aria2c -i links.txt -x 16')
  #os.system('rm links.txt')
  print "All good, you can download now"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(<yoursitehere>)
images = re.findall("src=\"[^\"]{8,240}", br.response().read()) 
for i in images: print i
br.close()
```

you need to filter results a bit, and tinker with RE, depending on HTML of particular site

Answer (score 0):

In order to scrape the full resolution image URL using `requests` and `beautifulsoup` library, you need to scrape data from the page source code with `regex`.

Basic explanation:

```py
# find all <script> tags:
soup.select('script')
```

```py
# match images data via regex:
matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
```

```py
# match desired images (full res size) via regex:

# https://kodlogs.com/34776/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes
# if you try to json.loads() without json.dumps() it will throw an error:
# "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                    matched_images_data_json)
```

```py
# Extract and decode them using bytes() and decode():
for fixed_full_res_image in matched_google_full_resolution_images:
    original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
    original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-and-Download-Google-Images-with-Python#bs4_original_images.py) that also downloads images to a folder:

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "pexels cat",
    "tbm": "isch", 
    "hl": "en",
    "ijn": "0",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


def get_images_data():

    print('\nGoogle Images Metadata:')
    for google_image in soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'):
        title = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['title']
        source = google_image.select_one('.fxgdke').text
        link = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['href']
        print(f'{title}\n{source}\n{link}\n')

    # this steps could be refactored to a more compact
    all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

    # # https://regex101.com/r/48UZhY/4
    matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
    # https://kodlogs.com/34776/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes
    # if you try to json.loads() without json.dumps it will throw an error:
    # "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
    matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
    matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

    # https://regex101.com/r/pdZOnW/3
    matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

    # https://regex101.com/r/NnRg27/1
    matched_google_images_thumbnails = ', '.join(
        re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(', ')

    print('Google Image Thumbnails:')  # in order
    for fixed_google_image_thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_google_image_thumbnail, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')

        # after first decoding, Unicode characters are still present. After the second iteration, they were decoded.
        google_image_thumbnail = bytes(google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(google_image_thumbnail)

    # removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
    removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', '', str(matched_google_image_data))

    # https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
    matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                       removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)


    print('\nDownloading Google Full Resolution Images:')  # in order
    for index, fixed_full_res_image in enumerate(matched_google_full_resolution_images):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(original_size_img)



get_images_data()


-------------
'''
Google Images Metadata:
9,000+ Best Cat Photos · 100% Free Download · Pexels Stock Photos
pexels.com
https://www.pexels.com/search/cat/
...

Google Image Thumbnails:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2cZsuRkkLWXOIsl9BZzbeaCcI0qav7nenDvvqi-YSm4nVJZYyljRsJZv6N5vS8hMNU_w&usqp=CAU
...

Full Resolution Images:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170986/pexels-photo-1170986.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-evg-culture-1170986.jpg&fm=jpg
https://images.pexels.com/photos/3777622/pexels-photo-3777622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with regex to match and extract needed data from the source code of the page, instead, you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get what you want faster.

Code to integrate to achieve your goal:

```py
import os, json # json for pretty output
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

def get_google_images():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "pexels cat",
      "tbm": "isch"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))


get_google_images()

---------------
'''
[
...
  {
    "position": 100, # img number
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRR1FCGhFsr_qZoxPvQBDjVn17e_8bA5PB8mg&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "pexels.com",
    "title": "Close-up of Cat · Free Stock Photo",
    "link": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/close-up-of-cat-320014/",
    "original": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2612982/pexels-photo-2612982.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "is_product": false
  }
]
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a more in-depth blog post about how to scrape [Google Images](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2), and [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.