# Python requests scrape image returns src in format "data:image/"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the first image off a google image search result as I don't want to do it manually for 100 keywords.

Using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


query="koko"
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + str(query) + "&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}


html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = soup.findAll("img")
```

`images[0]` is `<img alt="Koko, the gorilla who knew sign language, dies at 46 - Chicago Tribune" class="rg_i Q4LuWd" data-deferred="1" data-iid="0" height="157" jsname="Q4LuWd" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" width="200"/>`

The `src` returned has this format which I believe is base64 which I don't want, I want a normal image link.

If I disable javascript on my chrome browser and navigate to `https://www.google.com/search?q=koko&source=lnms&tbm=isch` and view the source code, the src of `img` returned is in the normal format that I need.

I can't manage to make `requests` html be the same as disabled javascript chrome.

I tried to change my User-Agent and tried to match the same one I have with chrome but it doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all images, set the `content-type` `header`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


query = "koko"
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + str(query) + "&source=lnms&tbm=isch"

HEADERS = {"content-type": "image/png"}

html = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for img in soup.find_all("img"):
    print(img["src"])
```

Output:

```
/images/branding/searchlogo/1x/googlelogo_desk_heirloom_color_150x55dp.gif
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYjINUgXtYyrUB4fKyaVxXCAkSyc_Q5b0QaeohUxmjdiIQwS_9CPXgWCXrUGQ&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1UnMwOo_8tpFkm04yby_I0HdMbfh6-GnhVWnKhOF1qnSP4ogODEn3AAo7V0M&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHwKA_l2i20z0yeGMr_imQcB-tffAfL0xcQAKmbFn1-NtVrHn8AtTv9aql2Q&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6UNEOYT2BwMVrjXo8WW6CS0rUHC0QLIqA-GdO1CLGk7mxw8lhWgMyI-uW4A&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT0dQsIKidzCcvdpvL0FDIfZ4Q3WL8GUKCCbwnK4V7FJ6nCGDVNbFmhnD7eOJ8&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeeYoW5maZW69VamkrN_vzjQoxIQl-RFrcZK58rCry1ZDpyIT6FVaG1IFsKw&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS3wy4vKh6ey8SAZHRxe-sKa1LEiBBdk6cbjELSGkoQn1YINb_YZSRanpOzR38&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnw0tBokCloEzt0QDpnTVvJYJr1ZDngx7Znz6nLCbjZbq2Vn3g57iEUKordQ&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZsq7Dy3-bT8miOPD_GE8_1X3isDl67A1ucNauliVlV4dIWgqleLY1OFyLjw&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsjLjEmJ2kFrdoiU1O0CE_d2bazVxl4IPaHJy2Ea_PhI-B0_4jXcDcuLo2PQ&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlvVOp05edZGkjz6q3QN8vqPsC-h-lIRlFyU16wYefNRG3zVlFQ2XeJRH3mMU&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT1QKRBEW1WOZs-bS15vTjzYutHLYNIis6Ji60bcJ_mXvA1tYjYYrD-Nk9cWMc&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQiqRS7ry4rNx8VNA4F6TUmm_ZaTtcp4iXokZF_WT-M7zEkF9YG7PpWKpPhSg&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSNtY7c7Qg-w9wXmKfhSHrop5b4tb2wCQoK5pLj_RA1eCPXAn4TNNtEVA8RG_U&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTH8zHuDssfuFW0PUpqNnQoG0yTkebQ194uy7auEzzodGuSAYqsF8flYTW3VAE&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSDowATaKwsMkiN1aQj9e6J2VfMUm6742KW3ifxqddk4UHWSX-WOWDeTDSi_w&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTaCZKWiYg2tEUNerLa1zcmUD25-ZVC0RCDY1E1iby3PnHIJOY7cFhTZd8Em8M&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfg8euHcq0wcUrtIHxleulXlTzbuehiZBb1DgJTEs3GdiG5l5bTdRt0Ug-Qg&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRPbAOCCA3diC-W5CtqbmpegeWPw-ReQPxBDaHN2YPH6OIqWC16dj5uNbhXhw&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnrICqNqL_KG42rZ2_B7nKdZr-INrqsdZqfzeAbFrJYsBez0GDvKtIrwJjP5U&s
```

Comment: Great use of headers!

Answer (score 0):

A complimentary answer to [MendelG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64216544/15164646) answer. While MendelG shows great use of headers, if you want to extract 100 pictures, then this method will not work. Try to apply `ijn=0` (*batch of 100 images*) URL param to request and you'll see that only this chunk of HTML will be returned:

```html
<div id="gsamd" style="display:none">[]</div><div data-piv="1" id="is_gsa_flags" style="display:none"></div>
```

Also, only thumbnail URLs and image metadata (*title, link*) will be returned with `headers` method. But titles are the same and URLs don't.

To extract more images you need to find all `<script>` tags, then use `regex` to match, extract and decode all extracted URLs.

Code that scrapes thumbnail/original size images and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Images-with-Python#main.py) (*try to read slowly*):

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "pexels cat",
    "tbm": "isch", 
    "hl": "en",
    "ijn": "0",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


def get_images_data():

    # this steps could be refactored to a more compact
    all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

    # https://regex101.com/r/48UZhY/4
    matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
    # https://kodlogs.com/34776/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes
    # if you try to json.loads() without json.dumps it will throw an error:
    # "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
    matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
    matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

    # https://regex101.com/r/pdZOnW/3
    matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

    # https://regex101.com/r/NnRg27/1
    matched_google_images_thumbnails = ', '.join(
        re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(', ')

    print('Google Image Thumbnails:')  # in order
    for fixed_google_image_thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_google_image_thumbnail, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')

        # after first decoding, Unicode characters are still present. After the second iteration, they were decoded.
        google_image_thumbnail = bytes(google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(google_image_thumbnail)

    # removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
    removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', '', str(matched_google_image_data))

    # https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
    matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                       removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)

    print('\nGoogle Full Resolution Images:')  # in order
    for fixed_full_res_image in matched_google_full_resolution_images:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(original_size_img)

get_images_data()

--------------
'''
Google Image Thumbnails:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSb48h3zks_bf6y7HnZGyGPn3s2TAHKKm_7kzxufi5nzbouJcQderHqoEoOZ4SpOuPDjfw&usqp=CAU
...

Google Full Resolution Images:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170986/pexels-photo-1170986.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this using [Goole Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=pexels%20cat&gl=us&hl=en&tbm=isch) to see what the output looks like.

The main difference is that you don't have to use `regex` or anything else to extract data from `HTML` or bypass blocks from Google (*if they appear*), all that needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Example code:

```py
import os, json # json for pretty output
from serpapi import GoogleSearch


def get_google_images():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), # environment variable
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "pexels cat",
      "tbm": "isch"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

get_google_images()

----------
'''
...
  {
    "position": 60, # img number
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRt-tXSZMBNLLX8MhavbBNkKmjJ7wNXxtdr5Q&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "pexels.com",
    "title": "1,000+ Best Cats Videos · 100% Free Download · Pexels Stock Videos",
    "link": "https://www.pexels.com/search/videos/cats/",
    "original": "https://images.pexels.com/videos/855282/free-video-855282.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "is_product": false
  }
...
'''
```

Check out what [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and [media type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/MIME_type) header do. More about [base64 and data urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

P.S. - I wrote a more in-depth blog post with visual representation about how to scrape [Google Images](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.