# Python 3.x BeautifulSoup crawling image URLs more than default values

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl image URLs with google image search window.

But I got only 20 URLs. I want more URLs than 20, and so what should I do?

### Source code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_images_links(searchTerm):

searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}&site=webhp&tbm=isch".format(searchTerm)
data = requests.get(searchUrl).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

imgs_urls = []

for img in img_tags:
    if img['src'].startswith("http"):
        imgs_urls.append(img['src'])

return(imgs_urls)

get_images_links('black jeans')
```

Comment: They have some images that will be regular links with <img src=http...> like you are searching for (the 20 you are finding) , and some images which can be viewed with a mouseover javascript action, that don't seem to get extracted by requests or beautifulsoup... but that we can see when browsing the source code in the element inspector. these are identified with a "data-src" tag, instead of the 'src' tag.

Comment: I suggest you use the Python selenium library. This will enable you to scroll down in the results page from google to acquire as many results as are immediately available. There are some suggestions about scrolling available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python. If you haven't used this product before then you would also need to learn its somewhat different approach for identifying HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

To get more than 20 image links you can use the `ijn` URL param, e.g `ijn=0` means 100 images and `ijn=1` means 200 images, and so on, and without using `selenium`. Find a better explanation in my [answer on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69222049/15164646).

```py
params = {
    "q": "pexels cat", # query
    "tbm": "isch",     # google images
    "hl": "en",        # language
    "ijn": "0",        # batch of 100 images
}
requests.get("YOUR_URL", params=params)
```

---

To scrape the full-res image URL with `requests` and `beautifulsoup` you need to scrape data from the page source code via `regex`.

Code to scrape and download full-res images and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Images-with-Python#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "pexels cat",
    "tbm": "isch", 
    "hl": "en",
    "ijn": "0",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


def get_images_data():

    print('\nGoogle Images Metadata:')
    for google_image in soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'):
        title = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['title']
        source = google_image.select_one('.fxgdke').text
        link = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['href']
        print(f'{title}\n{source}\n{link}\n')

    # this steps could be refactored to a more compact
    all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

    # # https://regex101.com/r/48UZhY/4
    matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
    # https://kodlogs.com/34776/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes
    # if you try to json.loads() without json.dumps it will throw an error:
    # "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
    matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
    matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

    # https://regex101.com/r/pdZOnW/3
    matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

    # https://regex101.com/r/NnRg27/1
    matched_google_images_thumbnails = ', '.join(
        re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(', ')

    print('Google Image Thumbnails:')  # in order
    for fixed_google_image_thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_google_image_thumbnail, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')

        # after first decoding, Unicode characters are still present. After the second iteration, they were decoded.
        google_image_thumbnail = bytes(google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(google_image_thumbnail)

    # removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
    removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', '', str(matched_google_image_data))

    # https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
    matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                       removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)


    print('\nDownloading Google Full Resolution Images:')  # in order
    for index, fixed_full_res_image in enumerate(matched_google_full_resolution_images):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(original_size_img)


get_images_data()


-------------
'''
Google Images Metadata:
9,000+ Best Cat Photos · 100% Free Download · Pexels Stock Photos
pexels.com
https://www.pexels.com/search/cat/
...

Google Image Thumbnails:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2cZsuRkkLWXOIsl9BZzbeaCcI0qav7nenDvvqi-YSm4nVJZYyljRsJZv6N5vS8hMNU_w&usqp=CAU
...

Full Resolution Images:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170986/pexels-photo-1170986.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-evg-culture-1170986.jpg&fm=jpg
https://images.pexels.com/photos/3777622/pexels-photo-3777622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Images API](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with `regex` to match and extract needed data from the source code of the page, instead, you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os, json # json for pretty output
from serpapi import GoogleSearch


def get_google_images():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "pexels cat",
      "tbm": "isch"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))


get_google_images()

---------------
'''
[
...
  {
    "position": 100, # img number
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRR1FCGhFsr_qZoxPvQBDjVn17e_8bA5PB8mg&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "pexels.com",
    "title": "Close-up of Cat · Free Stock Photo",
    "link": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/close-up-of-cat-320014/",
    "original": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2612982/pexels-photo-2612982.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "is_product": false
  }
]
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more in-depth blog post about how to scrape [Google Images](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2) and [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.