# What is the fix for this Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape this **URL** https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/type/C206.

I don't understand the meaning of this error below:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request

url = 'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/type/C206'
req = Request(url , headers = {
                          'accept':'*/*',
                          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'})

data = []

while True:
    print(url)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    data.append(pd.read_html(soup.select_one('tbody').prettify())[0])

    if soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers + div a[href]'):
        url = soup.select_one('div.pagenumbers + div a')['href']
    else:
        break
df = pd.concat(data)
df.to_csv('206.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False)
```

Comment: What do you expect `pd.read_html(soup.select_one('tbody tr.list')` should return, and **why**? Did you try to verify the data?

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395261/python-3-prettify-result) solves similar problem. Head there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `headers` with `requests`, which is the reason you're not getting the right HTML and the table you're after is the second one, not the first. Also, I'd highly recommend to use `requests` over `urllib.request`.

So, having said that, here's how to get all the tables from all the pages:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/type/C206'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36',
}

data = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    total_pages = int(
        BeautifulSoup(s.get(url, headers=headers).text, "lxml")
        .select("div.pagenumbers > a")[-1]
        .getText()
    )

    for page in range(1, total_pages + 1):
        print(f"Getting page: {page}...")
        data.append(
            pd.read_html(
                s.get(f"{url}/{page}", headers=headers).text,
                flavor="lxml",
            )[1]
        )

df = pd.concat(data)
df.to_csv('206.csv', sep=";", index=False)
```

Comment: Dear baduker, thank you for your above reply. I can't seen to locate where the 206.csv get posted on my PC (at it is not in the same folder as the code is, or the desktop folder...)

Comment: It *has* to be in the same location you run the code file is being run.

Comment: Dear baduker, many thanks for your reply.  I made a slight change to the last line of code to better format the output in the .csv file so that it is more readable friendly. ** df.to_csv('206.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False) **

Comment: For my own learning, the second table you are referring to is ' table class="hp" '.  I am not quite understanding why the while true loop, and specifying the ' table.hp ' could work.  As though the 1459 rows of record were not there.

Comment: Glad I could help!