# how can i make '\u' work in variable in python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode, byte

I got a string from network like:
s = '\u0070\u0079\u0074\u0068\u006f\u006e' or other
when i print(s)
it output '\u0070\u0079\u0074\u0068\u006f\u006e'
I want make '\u' work
when I print(s) 
it output 'python' (u'\u0070\u0079\u0074\u0068\u006f\u006e'=python)
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I got what you mean, but if you mean you want convert unicode characters with trailing slashes to real unicode characters, you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004431/text-with-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-in-python#comment4289832_4004439).

for python2 : `print s.decode('unicode-escape')`

for python3 : `print(bytes(s, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))`