# How to get more tags from requests.get()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am trying to get images from here.

https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=dog&rlz=1C1MSIM_koKR747KR747&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSn7Hm053YAhWLmpQKHXRpAh4Q_AUICigB&biw=1440&bih=794

You can check that there are a lot of 'img' tags by using Chrome Developer Tools. However, when I run the code below, I am disappointed to see the number 21. How can I increase it?

```
r=requests.get(url)
soup=bsp(r.text,'lxml')
len(soup.find_all('img'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem there is that the static page brought up by Google does not actually contain any image-search results. If you fetch the images contained in the result you are getting, you will find Google logo, and some structural images - maybe the tags they use to suggest search refining.

The actual images are loaded lazily by Javascript code, and it is very though to get those using requests - it will imply you checking which requests the client code of the page is doing to the server, by using your browser's tools, and mimicking those instead. This may or not be feasible, as it would be easy for Google to insert some tokens and pre-calculation to the lazy-requests that would be very hard to reverse-engineer from the Javascript on the page. Also, it most likely violates the terms of use of Google's image search.

You could try switching to [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to do the web search, instead of requests. As that uses a real browser, it will run the Javascript and make the actual lazy requests. It will work - but you will still be infringing the terms of use of the site, and it might not be long before you start getting captchas in your results.

So, the correct way to do this sort of thing is check if the service provider - Google Image Search in this case - have a public API you can make use of to perform your searches. On searching for that, you will find out that Google Image Search API is a deprecated thing, and it is now possible to use Google Search API to look for images. Currently they allow 100 free searches per day, and the service is charged after that.

Here is their link for understanding the API, and probably signing-up

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview?csw=1

After you are done understanding and getting an API Key, there is a Python wrapper for the API which can spare you a lot of headache and likely deliver you the URLs for the images:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Google-Search-API

Comment: Thank you very much for the long answer!!!! It is very helpful. But, regardless of the answer, I solved the problem by applying virous search keywords at multiple times instead of finding photos in one search. Anyway, my code can get 20 photos in one search.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse thumbnail images using `content-type: image/png` query parameter. Note that it will scrape only 20 images. If set to more, it will throw an error. Learn more about [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#types).

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {
    "q": "dog",
    "tbm": "isch", 
    "content-type": "image/png",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.select("img"):
  print(img["src"])

------
'''
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQq4fZiRGnMloOFKfYsBu91lbGkvT5RcLoa-ExEwbe6LDP3jl7zfZORPaprKA&s
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQAxU74QyJ8jn8Qq0ZK3ur_GkxjICcvmiC30DWnk03DEsi7YUgS8XXksdyybXY&s
...
'''
```

---

If you want to scrape *original resolution image* URLs, you need to use `regex` and in order to extract URLs from the `<script>` tags to match, extract and decode them. It will be a much-much faster scraping time compare to `selenium`.

Find all script tags:

```py
soup.select('script')
```

Secondly, to match the desired pattern using regex:

```py
# one of the regex patterns to find original size URL
re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]", SOME_VARIABLE)
```

Thirdly, iterate over matches, extract and decode each URL one by one:

```py
for SOME_VARIABLE in SOME_VARIABLE:
    # it needs to be decoded twice.
    # otherwise Unicode characters will be still present after the first decode.
    # yes, it is stupid. 
    original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
    original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-and-Download-Google-Images-with-Python#main.py) that also downloads images:

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "dog",     # query
    "tbm": "isch",  # img results
    "hl": "en",     # language 
    "ijn": "0",     # batch of 100 imgaes
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


def get_images_data():

    print('\nGoogle Images Metadata:')
    for google_image in soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'):
        title = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['title']
        source = google_image.select_one('.fxgdke').text
        link = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['href']
        print(f'{title}\n{source}\n{link}\n')

    # this steps could be refactored to a more compact
    all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

    # # https://regex101.com/r/48UZhY/4
    matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
    # https://kodlogs.com/34776/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes
    # if you try to json.loads() without json.dumps it will throw an error:
    # "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
    matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
    matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

    # https://regex101.com/r/pdZOnW/3
    matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

    # https://regex101.com/r/NnRg27/1
    matched_google_images_thumbnails = ', '.join(
        re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(', ')

    print('Google Image Thumbnails:')  # in order
    for fixed_google_image_thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_google_image_thumbnail, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')

        # after first decoding, Unicode characters are still present. After the second iteration, they were decoded.
        google_image_thumbnail = bytes(google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(google_image_thumbnail)

    # removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
    removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', '', str(matched_google_image_data))

    # https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
    matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                       removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)


    print('\nFull Resolution Images:')  # in order
    for index, fixed_full_res_image in enumerate(matched_google_full_resolution_images):

        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(original_size_img)


get_images_data()

---------------
'''
Google Images Metadata:
How dogs contribute to your health and happiness
medicalnewstoday.com
https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/322868
...

Google Image Thumbnails:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4Uiy-5lDV8xPcpy32U3gx7uqXLmHhi1tNt5qnJgaCCgc6RiCjiNePMTyVgVF4wrDqjgQ&usqp=CAU
...

Full Resolution Images:
https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-800x825.jpg
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out these URLs are located in the `<script>` tags and understand how to write `regex` for them or to maintain over time if something is changed in the HTML, instead you need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os, json # json for pretty output
from serpapi import GoogleSearch


def get_google_images():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "dog",
      "tbm": "isch"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

get_google_images()

---------------
'''
[
  {
    "position": 100,   # img number
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1somXixBxVLINMTbvzPfhX62xC2DimRvL-Q&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "hakaimagazine.com",
    "title": "The Dogs That Grew Wool and the People Who Love Them | Hakai Magazine",
    "link": "https://www.hakaimagazine.com/features/the-dogs-that-grew-wool-and-the-people-who-love-them/",
    "original": "https://www.hakaimagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/shiba-inu-wool-dogs.jpg",
    "is_product": false
  }
]
...
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more in-depth blog post about how to scrape and download images from [Google Images](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.