# Emoji converter by using python - (\ud83d\udc40) to the actual emoji symbol 

Tags: python, replace, text-files, emoji

I have simple (but extremely hard) question.

I'm looking for a way to convert a text file which contains this type of emoji code `(\ud83d\udc40)` and replace it with the one which will contain - actual emoji symbol

**E.G.**

```
with open(OUTPUT, "r+") as infileInsight:

    insightData = infileInsight.read()\
       .replace('\ud83d\udc40','')\
       ......

    with open(OUTPUT, "w+") as outfileInsight:
            outfileInsight.write(insightData)
```

**Regarding, that it is duplicated:**
If I do this way:

```
with open(OUTPUT, "r+") as infileInsight:

    insightData = infileInsight.read()\
       .replace('\ud83d\udc40','')\
       ......

    with open(OUTPUT, "w+") as outfileInsight:
            outfileInsight.write(insightData.decode('unicode-escape'))
```

**I have an error:**
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2600' in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Not really extremely hard, more like a duplicate of [text with unicode escape sequences to unicode in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004431/text-with-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-in-python)...

Comment: @NilsWerner This solution will not help, have tried it already.... it looks simple, but it just does not work...(

Comment: Did you try the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python. I know they are removing it, but since you can find it then you can replace instead of just removing.

Comment: Does the `infileInsight` file contain the literal characters `\u`? If so, when searching for something to replace, you'll need to have a string that contains those characters. The string you pass into `replace` doesn't contain a literal `\u`, it contains a unicode escape.

Comment: @DanielPryden have edit what file contains

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? The input data looks like it's ASCII, but what is the output encoding? (You're not specifying an output encoding, so the results depend on what version of Python you're using and on which platform. If you want to write Unicode characters you're going to need a Unicode-compatible encoding.)

Comment: To fix your latest error use `open(OUTPUT, "w+", encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: @MarkRansom does not solve my issue, I even separate the file from `\uhhhh` and `\uhhhh\uhhhh`, just do not want to change it.......

Answer (score 2):

You just need the `ensure_ascii=False` option in `json.dump`.

If you're creating this file in the first place, just pass that option.

If someone else gave you this JSON file and you want to change it to use Unicode characters directly in strings (as opposed to Unicode escapes as it is now), you can do something like this:

```
import json

with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            data = json.loads(line)
            json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
            outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Does the `json` module automatically convert surrogate code points into a single character?

Comment: Oh, I see... it's not just decoding the escapes, it's actually doing normalization. I wonder if that's a requirement for this implementation or if it's just a side-effect of the OP's approach.

Comment: @DanielPryden still have the same issue -
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2600' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128), em I doing something wrong?

Comment: @DanielPryden btw, I have provided a sample data for testing.