# Cant scrape images on google due to its changed URLs when web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-image-search

I am attempting to develop my very first web scraper using Beautiful Soup in Python.
The aim is for the scraper to ask the user for an input, do a normal Google images search and download all required number of images.
Earlier it was rg-meta tag that changed to rg_i Q4LuWd ,changes are made to the code. Still it cant scrape images.
What more changes are required to find and download the images.
No errors or exceptions are found ,the program runs but couldnt find urls of the image

```
import os
import json 
import requests # to sent GET requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # to parse HTML

# user can input a topic and a number
# download first n images from google image search

GOOGLE_IMAGE = \
    'https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1873&bih=990&'

# The User-Agent request header contains a characteristic string 
# that allows the network protocol peers to identify the application type, 
# operating system, and software version of the requesting software user agent.
# needed for google search
usr_agent = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}
SAVE_FOLDER = 'images'

def main():
    if not os.path.exists(SAVE_FOLDER):
        os.mkdir(SAVE_FOLDER)
    download_images()
    
def download_images():
    # ask for user input
    data = input('What are you looking for? ')
    n_images = int(input('How many images do you want? '))

    print('Start searching...')
    
    # get url query string
    searchurl = GOOGLE_IMAGE + 'q=' + data
    print(searchurl)

    # request url, without usr_agent the permission gets denied
    response = requests.get(searchurl, headers=usr_agent)
    html = response.text

    # find all divs where class='rg_i Q4LuWd'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'rg_i Q4LuWd'},limit=n_images)
**Earlier it was rg-meta tag that changed to rg_i Q4LuWd**
    print(results)
    # extract the link from the div tag
    imagelinks= []
    for re in results:
        text = re.text # this is a valid json string
        text_dict= json.loads(text) # deserialize json to a Python dict
        link = text_dict['ou']
        # image_type = text_dict['ity']
        imagelinks.append(link)

    print(f'found {len(imagelinks)} images')
    print('Start downloading...')

    for i, imagelink in enumerate(imagelinks):
        # open image link and save as file
        response = requests.get(imagelink)
        
        imagename = SAVE_FOLDER + '/' + data + str(i+1) + '.jpg'
        with open(imagename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)

    print('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please share [error/exception](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion) which you are getting?

Comment: Google won't be very happy about that - they will throttle your algorithm very quickly, or use a captcha to completely block it. You should look for an API to do that (it'll probably be free for a few queries, but might cost you money if you intend to have high volume of searches).

Answer (score 0):

It's because image URLs are located in the `<script>` tags and in order to get them you need to use `regex` instead, to match, extract and decode them. *Also, I'm not sure how to control the output image amount during `input()`.*

Find all <`script>` tags:

```py
soup.select('script')
```

Match images data via `regex`:

```py
matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
```

Match desired images (*full res size*) via `regex`:

```py
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                    matched_images_data)
```

Extract and decode them using `bytes()` and `decode()`:

```py
for fixed_full_res_image in matched_google_full_resolution_images:
    original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
    original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

To save images you can use [`urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)`](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/save+image+from+url+python) (*[more in-depth](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-download-an-image-using-python-38a75cfa21c)*):

```py
# often times it will throw 404 error, so to avoid it we need to pass user-agent

opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

urllib.request.urlretrieve(original_size_img, f'LOCAL_FOLDER_NAME/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME.jpg')
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Images-with-Python#bs4_original_images.py) that scrapes more (*try to read it slowly*):

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "pexels cat",
    "tbm": "isch", 
    "hl": "en",
    "ijn": "0",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


def get_images_data():

    print('\nGoogle Images Metadata:')
    for google_image in soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'):
        title = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['title']
        source = google_image.select_one('.fxgdke').text
        link = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['href']
        print(f'{title}\n{source}\n{link}\n')

    # this steps could be refactored to a more compact
    all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

    # # https://regex101.com/r/48UZhY/4
    matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
    # https://kodlogs.com/34776/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes
    # if you try to json.loads() without json.dumps it will throw an error:
    # "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
    matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
    matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

    # https://regex101.com/r/pdZOnW/3
    matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

    # https://regex101.com/r/NnRg27/1
    matched_google_images_thumbnails = ', '.join(
        re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(', ')

    print('Google Image Thumbnails:')  # in order
    for fixed_google_image_thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_google_image_thumbnail, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')

        # after first decoding, Unicode characters are still present. After the second iteration, they were decoded.
        google_image_thumbnail = bytes(google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(google_image_thumbnail)

    # removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
    removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', '', str(matched_google_image_data))

    # https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
    matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                       removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)


    print('\nDownloading Google Full Resolution Images:')  # in order
    for index, fixed_full_res_image in enumerate(matched_google_full_resolution_images):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(original_size_img)

        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Download original images

        print(f'Downloading {index} image...')
        
        opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

        urllib.request.urlretrieve(original_size_img, f'Images/original_size_img_{index}.jpg')


get_images_data()


-------------
'''
Google Images Metadata:
9,000+ Best Cat Photos · 100% Free Download · Pexels Stock Photos
pexels.com
https://www.pexels.com/search/cat/
...

Google Image Thumbnails:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2cZsuRkkLWXOIsl9BZzbeaCcI0qav7nenDvvqi-YSm4nVJZYyljRsJZv6N5vS8hMNU_w&usqp=CAU
...

Full Resolution Images:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170986/pexels-photo-1170986.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-evg-culture-1170986.jpg&fm=jpg
Downloaded 0 image...
https://images.pexels.com/photos/3777622/pexels-photo-3777622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
Downloaded 1 image...
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with `regex` to match and extract needed data from the source code of the page, instead, you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get what you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os, urllib.request, json # json for pretty output
from serpapi import GoogleSearch


def get_google_images():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "pexels cat",
      "tbm": "isch"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    # print(json.dumps(results['suggested_searches'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
    print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

    # -----------------------
    # Downloading images

    for index, image in enumerate(results['images_results']):

        print(f'Downloading {index} image...')
        
        opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image['original'], f'SerpApi_Images/original_size_img_{index}.jpg')


get_google_images()

---------------
'''
[
...
  {
    "position": 100, # img number
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRR1FCGhFsr_qZoxPvQBDjVn17e_8bA5PB8mg&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "pexels.com",
    "title": "Close-up of Cat · Free Stock Photo",
    "link": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/close-up-of-cat-320014/",
    "original": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2612982/pexels-photo-2612982.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "is_product": false
  }
]

Downloading 0 image...
Downloading 1 image...
Downloading 2 image...
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a more detailed blog post about how to scrape [Google Imgaes](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.