# How to increase dynamic loading amount using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm doing a program that downloads X amount of images from Google based on a search query. Here's the code

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

query = input('query: ')
query.strip()

url = f'https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q={query}'
html = requests.get(url.format(page=0, pageSize=15))

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser") 

images = soup.find_all('img')

print(len(images))
```

As you may know, Google Images is a dynamically loading page. The print function returns only 21 results but this seems a really low amount, is there any way to increment this number to 100 or so? I won't want to use Selenium since it takes way too long to load and I need those images pretty much instantly

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `regex` in order to match and extract original size images.

Instead of `soup.find_all('img')` you need to find all `<script>` tags, e.g. `soup.find_all('script')` that contain needed URLs and then use regular expressions to match and extract those URLs.

To get more images you can pass `"ijn": "0"` parameter, where `"0"` means 100 images, `"1"` means 200 images, and so on.

---

Code (*FULL example downloads images, the code below only extracts URLs*) and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Images-with-Python#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "pexels cat",
    "tbm": "isch", 
    "hl": "en",
    "ijn": "0",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


def get_images_data():

    # this steps could be refactored to a more compact
    all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

    # # https://regex101.com/r/48UZhY/4
    matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
    # https://kodlogs.com/34776/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes
    # if you try to json.loads() without json.dumps it will throw an error:
    # "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
    matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
    matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

    # https://regex101.com/r/pdZOnW/3
    matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

    # https://regex101.com/r/NnRg27/1
    matched_google_images_thumbnails = ', '.join(
        re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(', ')

    print('Google Image Thumbnails:')  # in order
    for fixed_google_image_thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_google_image_thumbnail, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')

        # after first decoding, Unicode characters are still present. After the second iteration, they were decoded.
        google_image_thumbnail = bytes(google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(google_image_thumbnail)

    # removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
    removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', '', str(matched_google_image_data))

    # https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
    matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                       removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)

    print('\nGoogle Full Resolution Images:')  # in order
    for fixed_full_res_image in matched_google_full_resolution_images:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(original_size_img)


--------------
'''
Google Image Thumbnails:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSb48h3zks_bf6y7HnZGyGPn3s2TAHKKm_7kzxufi5nzbouJcQderHqoEoOZ4SpOuPDjfw&usqp=CAU
...

Google Full Resolution Images:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170986/pexels-photo-1170986.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
...
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to dig through the source code of the page trying to find desired URLs. Instead, you only need to iterate over JSON string and get desired data.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os, json # json for pretty output
from serpapi import GoogleSearch


def get_google_images():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "pexels cat",
      "tbm": "isch"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

-----------
'''
  {
    "position": 60, # img number
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRt-tXSZMBNLLX8MhavbBNkKmjJ7wNXxtdr5Q&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "pexels.com",
    "title": "1,000+ Best Cats Videos · 100% Free Download · Pexels Stock Videos",
    "link": "https://www.pexels.com/search/videos/cats/",
    "original": "https://images.pexels.com/videos/855282/free-video-855282.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "is_product": false
  }
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a more detailed blog post with a visual representation about how to scrape [Google Images](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.