# Issue requesting when scraping images from google using 'src' tag, how to scrape images from google using beautiful soup?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-colaboratory, google-image-search

I am a newbie to python at best. I have been attempting to make a function to download a specific number of images from a desired google image search into a specific folder in your google drive. But I have hit a snag that I am unable to fix; please can someone point out where I am going wrong or point me in the right direction to fix it. I believe the issue is `im = requests.get(link)` (line 36). So far, I have the following:

```
# mount the drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')


#module import
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#define parameters of search
query = input("Images of:") 
print("Number of images:")
NumberOfImages = int(input())
FolderLocation = input("Input Folder Location:")
image_type="ActiOn"
query= query.split()
query='+'.join(query)
url="https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+query+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

# soup
request = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img')

# loop to save
tik = 0
for image in images:
  if tik <= NumberOfImages:
    link = image['src']
    name = query+"_"+str(tik)
    print(link, name)
    with open(FolderLocation+"/"+name+".jpg",'wb') as f:
      im = requests.get(link)
      f.write(im.content)
      print("Writing "+name+ " to file")
    tik +=1
  else:
    break
```

Is this an issue with requesting the 'src' links from google, or is there something else I am missing out?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to scrape the full-res image URL using `requests` and `beautifulsoup` you need to scrape data from the page source (*CTRL+U*) code via `regex`.

Find all `<script>` tags:

```py
soup.select('script')
```

Match images data via `regex` from the `<script>` tags:

```py
matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
```

Match desired images (full res size) via `regex`:

```py
matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                    matched_images_data_json)
```

Extract and decode them using `bytes()` and `decode()` and tell how much elements you want to extract with `list()` slicing `[:20]` (*grabs first 20 images*):

```py
for fixed_full_res_image in matched_google_full_resolution_images[:20]:
    original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
    original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-and-Download-Google-Images-with-Python#bs4_original_images.py) that also downloads images:

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "pexels cat",
    "tbm": "isch", 
    "hl": "en",
    "ijn": "0",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


def get_images_data():

    print('\nGoogle Images Metadata:')
    for google_image in soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'):
        title = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['title']
        source = google_image.select_one('.fxgdke').text
        link = google_image.select_one('.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')['href']
        print(f'{title}\n{source}\n{link}\n')

    # this steps could be refactored to a more compact
    all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

    # # https://regex101.com/r/48UZhY/4
    matched_images_data = ''.join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    
    # https://kodlogs.com/34776/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes
    # if you try to json.loads() without json.dumps it will throw an error:
    # "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
    matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
    matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)

    # https://regex101.com/r/pdZOnW/3
    matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\[\"GRID_STATE0\",null,\[\[1,\[0,\".*?\",(.*),\"All\",', matched_images_data_json)

    # https://regex101.com/r/NnRg27/1
    matched_google_images_thumbnails = ', '.join(
        re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(', ')

    print('Google Image Thumbnails:')  # in order
    for fixed_google_image_thumbnail in matched_google_images_thumbnails:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_google_image_thumbnail, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')

        # after first decoding, Unicode characters are still present. After the second iteration, they were decoded.
        google_image_thumbnail = bytes(google_image_thumbnail_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(google_image_thumbnail)

    # removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
    removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', '', str(matched_google_image_data))

    # https://regex101.com/r/fXjfb1/4
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821774/15164646
    matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                       removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)

    print('\nFull Resolution Images:')  # in order
    for index, fixed_full_res_image in enumerate(matched_google_full_resolution_images):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004439/15164646 comment by Frédéric Hamidi
        original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
        print(original_size_img)

        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Download original images

        # print(f'Downloading {index} image...')
        
        # opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
        # opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582')]
        # urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

        # urllib.request.urlretrieve(original_size_img, f'Bs4_Images/original_size_img_{index}.jpg')


get_images_data()


-------------
'''
Google Images Metadata:
9,000+ Best Cat Photos · 100% Free Download · Pexels Stock Photos
pexels.com
https://www.pexels.com/search/cat/
other results ...

Google Image Thumbnails:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2cZsuRkkLWXOIsl9BZzbeaCcI0qav7nenDvvqi-YSm4nVJZYyljRsJZv6N5vS8hMNU_w&usqp=CAU
other results ...

Full Resolution Images:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/1170986/pexels-photo-1170986.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-evg-culture-1170986.jpg&fm=jpg
other results ...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to deal with regex, bypass blocks from Google, and maintain it over time if something crashes. Instead, you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Example code to integrate:

```py
import os, json # json for pretty output
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

def get_google_images():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "pexels cat",
      "tbm": "isch"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))


get_google_images()

---------------
'''
[
... # other images 
  {
    "position": 100, # img number
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRR1FCGhFsr_qZoxPvQBDjVn17e_8bA5PB8mg&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "pexels.com",
    "title": "Close-up of Cat · Free Stock Photo",
    "link": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/close-up-of-cat-320014/",
    "original": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2612982/pexels-photo-2612982.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "is_product": false
  }
]
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a more in-depth blog post about [how to scrape Google Images](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2), and [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.